# Printing macro value using #pragma message after forming its name

Tags: c, gcc, macros, pragma

I'm trying to concatenate name parts to create the macro name and after that, printing the value of the macro using `#pragma message`.

How could I form the macro name (`VAR_123_1`) by concatenating `VAR_`, `id`, and `_7`?

I need to print the value `1` using `#pragma message`.

My latest try:

```
#define VAR_123_7 1

#define id 123

#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

#define XA7(x) VAR_## x ##_7

#define XXA7() XA7(id)

#pragma message "value is: A " STR(XXA7())

int main() {
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to do the same indirection with the token-pasting operator `##` that you did with your stringizing operator `#` so that `id` will be resolved before processing.

Comment: Right. It workes! `#define XXA7(id) XA7(id)` `#pragma message "value is: A " STR(XXA7(id))`